# telnet connections give a blank screen where I cannot type, returns 400 code after typing anthing

Tags: networking, telnet

I made sure that I have telnet enabled in the MS control panel, but every time I enter something like:

```
telnet gaia.cs.umass.edu 80
```

the response is:

```
connecting to gaia.cs.umass.edu...
```

followed by a blank screen where I cannot see any text that I type (the cursor does not move either). If I click enter or backspace it goes back to cmd and displays:

[

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sat, 05 Feb 2022 21:39:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.4.27 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.16.3
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />                                                                                                                                                                                     </p>
</body></html>
Connection to host lost.
C:\WINDOWS\system32>telnet gaia.cs.umass.edu 23
Connecting To gaia.cs.umass.edu...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1naXN.png)

I have tried alternatively entering:

```
telnet
set localecho
o gaia.cs.umass.edu 80
```

which results in

```
Press any key to continue...
```

and then returns to telnet with the output

```
Connection to host lost.
```

It seems like its timing out before I have the option to do anything.

Is there something I'm missing here? I thought I had the command typed correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are talking to an HTTP server. It is expecting an HTTP request. You are not sending an HTTP request. Are you expecting it to behave like a Telnet server? It won't.

Answer (score 0):

I am going through the same problem.

But I GET a response by doing in two ways:

1. type `telnet gaia.cs.umass.edu 80` in cmd, when enter into the interative mode, ignore the blank, just paste `GET /kurose_ross/interactive/index.php HTTP/1.1`, press Enter, and paste `Host: gaia.cs.mass.edu`, press Enter twice!!!
2. type `telnet`, enter Microsoft Telnet mode(I don't know if I call it right), then type

> Microsoft Telnet> o gaia.cs.umass.edu 80

and then ignore the interface display, just paste `GET /kurose_ross/interactive/index.php HTTP/1.1`, press Enter, and paste `Host: gaia.cs.mass.edu`, press Enter twice!!!

The response I get is like this:
[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1GQT.png)

Not sure if it's the correct information that was designed this year.

Also, I find a reasonable answer about the 'blank' thing answered by Thomas Tydal after figuring out these two ways: [link](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-my-Telnet-go-black-when-I-type-a-request)